# split multiple arrays into variables based on name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Thinking of a better way of doing this - I have these arrays available:

```
   var model1 = ['10', '20', '30', '40','50','60'];
   var model2 = ['80', '100', '200', '300','400','500'];
   var model3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6'];
```

and in my code where I use them I do:

```
    $scope.sli['model1'][0]=0;
    $scope.sli['model1'][1]=10;
    $scope.sli['model1'][2]=20;
    $scope.sli['model1'][3]=30;
    $scope.sli['model1'][4]=40;
    $scope.sli['model1'][5]=50;
    $scope.sli['model1'][6]=60;
```

for each model to declare them to use later.

What would be a better way to do in a for loop, so I simply pass the model array name, split the array into an index, so if new models are added, they are actually automatically picked up, rather than declaring them individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont need to assign an array

if `model1` has been defined as:

```
var model1 = ['10', '20', '30', '40','50','60'];
```

you can simply do

```
$scope.sli['model1'] = model1
```

and access individual elements 
like `$scope.sli['model1'][0]` to get `"10"`